# JS click function open url in new windown

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hyperlink

I create a link with text using html and i want to create when user click it goes to specific url. I new in javascript!!

here my code

```
<a class="dt-button add_new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#">
<span>Add new</span>
</a>
```

my script

```
$("dt-button add_new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new").click(function () {
window.location="http://project.co/add-new/";
});
```

**UPDATE**
I have create my script

```
 let classic = document.getElementsByClassName('add_new DTTT_button DTTT_button_new');
for (var i=0; i < classic.length; i++) {
classic[i].addEventListener("click", clickfunc, false);
}
function.clickfunc(){
document.location.href="http://google.com";
}
```

but give error unexpected token ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any class named `add_new`. Using single unique class in `getElementsByClassName` parameter is enough. Try the following:

```
let classic = document.getElementsByClassName('dt-button');
for (var i=0; i < classic.length; i++) {
  classic[i].addEventListener("click", clickfunc, false);
}
function clickfunc(){
  window.open("http://google.com","_blank");
}
```

Comment: @Ibrahim Quraisy, I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

javascript open new window

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

Answer (score 0):

use follwing code

```
$("dt-button add_new_table_entry DTTT_button 
DTTT_button_new").click(function () {
window.open("http://project.co/add-new/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function :

```
function openlink()
{
window.open("http://project.co/add-new/","mywindow","menubar=no,resizable=1,width=400,height=400");
}
```

then you call the function using this :

```
<a href="javascript:openlink();">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it , it will work, here on click of class = add_new_table_entry, javascript click event gets called and in same window redirection happens
we use window.location for redirection
    
Add new

```
$(".add_new_table_entry").click(function () {
        window.location ="http://project.co/add-new/";
    });
```